# Limitting Child processes and waiting until one is complete

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a GET route set up when that GET route is reached it will call a function in my controller. This function does a long computation and so I forked it. Without forking the process takes around 15 seconds, if the client does a call then other calls would get blocked for 15 seconds until it's done and then the first one that has called is helped. The maximum amounts of long computation can't exceed 3 forks. If there are more than 3 forks I want the client to wait until a fork is done.

I've tested a if statement that lets the user sleep but if another call comes in at the right time then the user that is sleeping has to wait even longer, I've also put a while loop but then eventually the memory runs out. I just can't wrap my head around it. Any help is appreciated.

```
  app.route('/calculation')
    .get(todoList.calculation);
```

```
exports.calculation = [
  check('parameter')
    .isHexadecimal(),

    async function(req, res, next) { /* the rest of the existing function */ 
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    }

  while(numRunning == 3){

  } 

  try {

    const forked = fork('server/forked-longComputation.js');
    ++numRunning;
    var test = req.query.calculation;

    forked.send(test);
    forked.on('message', (sum) => {
      console.log('sent sum to client');
      --numRunning;
      forked.kill();
      res.json(sum);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    --numRunning;
    console.log('Err');
    res.json({ error: err.message || err.toString() });
  }
}
];
```

Comment: Once you hit the `while` loop the program is stuck in an infinite loop.  The event loop will never be prempted and the program will never have the opportunity to yield to the `forked` callback.  https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#event-loop-explained